# Python match a paragraph with multiple line-breaks using regex

Tags: python, regex, paragraph, findall

I try to Match Paragraphs using Python and Re.

An example of a text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
>   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
>   sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
>   rebum.
>
> **two or more line breaks here**
>
> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet.
>
> **two or more line breaks here**
>
> Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
>   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
>   diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
>   rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet.

This Expression seems to almost do the job:

```
paragraphs = re.findall(r'(?s)((?:[^\n][\n]?)+)', textContent)
```

But I want to make sure to only match if there are two or more line-breaks. Currently it matches too often.

Edit:

```
ART. WEFWEFEW
  1 SDVSDRG: **<at the momemnt it breaks here, but it shouldnt>**
     a. wevvdfvdfd
     b. sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdghtrhrth
```

Edit2:

```
ART. WEFWEFEW
   1 SDVSDRG: 
      **here are two line-breaks, but dont split this paragraph**
      **at the momemnt it breaks here, but it shouldnt**
     a. wevvdfvdfd
     b. sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdghtrhrth
```

Comment: Are you using an online regex tester to try out patterns?

Comment: yes using:
https://pythex.org/

Comment: `two or more line-breaks` OR `two-or-more empty lines`?

Comment: what would be the difference?

Comment: `Currently it matches too often.` - Which portions of the example text do you expect `.findall()` to return?

Comment: 3 matches with 3 paragraphs in the exmaple above. but at the moment it also creates matches if there are less than two breaks, maybe i can update the example

Comment: Maybe you just want `re.split(r'\n{2,}',text)`  or `re.split(r'\n{3,}',text)`, or `re.findall(r'.+(?:\n(?!\n).*)*',text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew split \n{2,} seems not bad. 
how could i say split \n{2,} as long as they are not followed by a ':' char?

Comment: It is `re.split(r'\n{2,}(?![\n:])',text)`. Does it work as expected? I will post with explanations if it does.

Comment: sorry i was wrong, it should be the other way around... : followed by two or more \n  should not split

Comment: Try `r'(?<!:)\n{2,}'` with re.split but it won't work well I think as if there are more than 2 linebreaks, the pattern will find matches between the newlines. You should consider re-writing it for `re.findall`. Something like `re.findall(r'(?m)^.+(?:\n(?!\n).*|(?<=:)\n{2,}.*)*', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iRccW7/1)).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this regex `(?m)(?:.+(?:\n.)?)+` on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/bFUH6l/3), where you can also get an explanation of it.

Sample Python code that uses this regex:

```
import re
import pprint

textContent = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet.


Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.



ART. WEFWEFEW
  1 SDVSDRG:
     a. wevvdfvdfd
     b. sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdghtrhrth'''

pprint.pprint(re.findall(r'(?m)(?:.+(?:\n.)?)+', textContent))
```

Output:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\n'
 'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore\n'
 'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et\n'
 'accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.',
 'Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem\n'
 'ipsum dolor sit amet.',
 'Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam\n'
 'nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna\n'
 'aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et\n'
 'justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no\n'
 'sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
 'ART. WEFWEFEW\n'
 '  1 SDVSDRG:\n'
 '     a. wevvdfvdfd\n'
 '     b. sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdghtrhrth']
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/edit/PDKK41445).